# #1064 mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error report while importing my sql file.

this is the error report :

> **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
>     employerhdmf decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00'' at line 8**

here's the code :

```
CREATE DATABASE kafik9; USE kafik9;

--
-- Table structure for table 'prlemphdmffile'
-- CREATE TABLE prlemphdmffile (   counterindex int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,   payrollid varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',  
employeeid varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',   grosspay varchar(12,2)
NOT NULL default '0.00',   employerhdmf decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default
'0.00',     employeehdmf decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',    
total varchar(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',   fsmonth tinyint(4) NOT
NULL default '0',   fsyear double NOT NULL default '0',    PRIMARY KEY
(counterindex) ) TYPE=InnoDB;
```

there's anybody can help what is going wrong here? thanks in advance

Comment: Not with it formatted that way.

Comment: Why is the first line of the CREATE TABLE statement commented?

Comment: so, what i suppose to do, sir?

Comment: `varchar(12,2) NOT NULL`

Comment: some example would be very helpful

Comment: i dont think varchar can have two values

Comment: sorry, that should be decimal, not varchar. so just figured out varchar in that case is decimal

Comment: fyi, im using :
5.5.27 - MySQL
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10 - 20111026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is `varchar(12,2)`. From your comment sounds like that is meant to be `decimal`. You need to change both occurrences to `decimal(12,2)`.

Next, `TYPE=InnoDB` needs to be `ENGINE=InnoDB`

This query will work:

```
  CREATE TABLE prlemphdmffile (   
     counterindex int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,   
     payrollid varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',  
     employeeid varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',   
     grosspay decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',   
     employerhdmf decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',     
     employeehdmf decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',    
     total decimal(12,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',   
     fsmonth tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',   
     fsyear double NOT NULL default '0',    
     PRIMARY KEY(counterindex) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

From the mysql [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-innodb-tables.html):

```
CREATE TABLE customers (a INT, b CHAR (20), INDEX (a)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

The older term TYPE is supported as a synonym for ENGINE for backward compatibility, but ENGINE is the preferred term and TYPE is deprecated.
```

It sounds like `TYPE` *should* still work even though it is deprecated, but it did not work on my machine. Changing to `ENGINE` did the trick.

**Update**

As pointed out in a comment by @eggyal, the above reference is from the mysql 5.0 docs. See the comment below for more information.

Comment: Note that you have linked to the MySQL v5.0 documentation. More recent versions of that page make no reference to `TYPE`; and the [Release Notes for MySQL 5.1.8](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.1/en/news-5-1-8.html) state "*The following deprecated constructs now generate warnings, and they are removed as of MySQL 5.5 ... The `TYPE` table option to specify the storage engine for `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` (use `ENGINE`).*"

Comment: @eggyal Thanks, you're right - I made an update to my answer to note this.

Answer (score 0):

change these part

```
grosspay varchar(12,2) NOT NULL -> grosspay decimal(12,2) NOT NULL

total varchar(12,2) NOT NULL -> total decimal(12,2) NOT NULL
```